# Generating unique permutations in a predictable order with Python and Sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I have a list of elements in python.  In the final code, the length of the list will be variable and the elements of my list much more lengthy, but I can demonstrate my question with three dummy elements.

Basically, for any list of length n, there will be n-1 identical elements, and 1 unique element.

So, in the example of three elements I have:

```
test = ['b', 'a', 'a']
```

For small cases such as 3, where I can verify by eye the order of the elements, I have been using a function from the Sympy module, as below:

```
permutations = list(multiset_permutations(test))
```

However, once cases become too large, I'm not certain that the order will be predictable.  And, checking the [official documentations](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/iterables.html) doesn't really clarify the issue for me very well.

Is there a way to generate these permutations in a predictable order such that I could know, for example:

```
permutations[0] = ['b', 'a', 'a']
permutations[1] = ['a', 'b', 'a']
permutations[2] = ['a', 'a', 'b']
```

Thank you for any help that can be given.

Comment: In what way are you concerned about the result? It looks like reversed lexical order.

Comment: I've edited my question to remove that ambiguity. The order is irrelevant as long as it is predictable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elements are ordered before the permutations are generated by `multiset_permutations`. Your result will not depend on the order of the input items.